# Flash Builder 4.5 strange behavior?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I am recently experiencing some very strange behavious with Fash Builder 4.5.
Sometime it just do not wish to open MXML files, false reporting them as a missing resources.

- Did someone had this issue, and how did fixed it ?

P.S. : I found a quick patch solution ( but not good one )  : If i open the files reported as a missing, and change their 1st row with something which would be a mistake ( some typo ) and open them again with Flash Builder, then it shows the source, and repairing the just created error turn the things in order again.. :| really strange...

Comment: Are you using a versioning system?

Comment: nope. i havent install any. just flash builder as it is. nothings changed.

Comment: Mm. Are your project files located on a network drive perhaps?

Comment: nope. it is right on my desktop.

Comment: OK. One more try; then I'm afraid I'll be out of questions: did you edit these files with another editor (perhaps while FlashBuilder was running)?

Comment: Nope. It happening on random. When you open / close flash build, especially if u close it without close the project, there is good chance to happen ( 10% or something ) :|

Comment: What type of project is this?  Have you tried to refresh the directory that they are in?  Are you using Windows or Mac?  Can you give the exact error your seeing?  ( A screenshot ) and steps to rproduce.

Comment: Windows 7, i have refreshed the directory, i have even changed the files names, and when i did that - they could be opened once again, but if i turn back their original names, they becomes false reported as missing once again.

Comment: The error is : Resource is missing : debugPrj/Main.xmls - i will add screenshot next time when it happen, because i fixed the fast way everything i could atm just to continue working...

Comment: ADD : I just found a way to reproduce it : Open a project, open some MXML file, then open a few AS files, and leave the workspace on the last AS file, then close the Flash Builder, and open it once again, and it will report that the files is missing ( at least here it does ). the project must remain opened at the closing flash builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like it is internal issue, which is half-fixed at the moment.
after reloading / refreshing the files on the tree, and sometime opening/closing Flash Build the issue goin.

Update :

```
Project -> Clean
```

fix the issue in most of the cases.